# glReadPixels failed with format GL_ALPHA

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glreadpixels

I wanna draw font on the android game by the freetype library. Get the glyph texture by the library and upload to the FBO, which i used to rendering the string label;

when i run this code, it would be ok, and i get the excepted data, the font shows ok,

```
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j ++) {
            glReadPixels ( 0, j, width, 1,
                           GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data + j*bytesPerRow);
    }
```

But after i change the format to GL_ALPHA, it is always return 0 on the android device,
and the gl error log: got error: 0x500, so it means ,i can't read the pixels by GL_ALPHA?
the wrong code as:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j ++) {
            glReadPixels ( 0, j, width, 1,
                           GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data + j*bytesPerRow);
    }
```

i don't know why, any help?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL ES is only required to support 2 format / data type pairs in a call to `glReadPixels (...).`

1. `GL_RGBA`, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` (you already know this one)
2. Query: `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT` and `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE`

You have discovered unfortunately that `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is ***NOT*** the second supported format / data type pair.

To figure out what the second supported pair is, consider the following code:

```
GLint imp_fmt, imp_type;

glGetIntegerv (GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, &imp_fmt);
glGetIntegerv (GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE,   &imp_type);

printf ("Supported Color Format/Type: %x/%x\n", imp_fmt, imp_type);
```

You will have to adjust the code accordingly, since this is C and you are using Java... but you get the idea.

Chances are very good that your implementation does not have a single-channel format for use with `glReadPixels (...)` considering there is no single-channel color-renderable format without the extension: `GL_EXT_texture_rg`.

Comment: many thanks,btw, i am using c and objc, and i have developing android game, so i should use some java...